# elasticsearch script on a list of object

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, lucene, kibana-4

my data looks like

```
{  
   'members': [{'name': 'x', 'hobby': 'y'},
               {'name', 'x2', 'hobby': 'y'}],
   'n': 100
}
```

my target is I can create dashboard that:

1. group all the data with 'name'.

the solution I was trying:
1. create a script "member_names": ['x', 'x2'] in kibana index setting page. 
2. make dashboard with 'member_names'

it this possible?  I'm using kibana 4 and there es version is 2.2.1. 
my current issues are the script in kibana only support lucene, which be t limited to basic arithmetic, bitwise and comparison operations. so I can't use it.

My questions are:

1. How to let kibana setting page support groovy?
2. how can I write the script to fulfill my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert about Kibana, but you can search in google "groovy site:www.elastic.co" and returns e.g.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting

for the groovy part you can simply user member_names=data.members.name:

```
data=['members' : [['name': 'x', 'hobby': 'y'],['name':'x2','hobby':'y']] , 'n': 100 ]
member_names=data.members.name
assert member_names==['x', 'x2']
```